# grpc client side load balacing fails with error : WARNING: [Channel<1>: ()] Failed to resolve name

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying implement grpc client side load balancing for my java server.
One [server](https://github.com/rajcspsg/grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/raj/grpc/server/bank/lb/GrpcServer1.java) runs on port 6565 and another [server](https://github.com/rajcspsg/grpc-gradle-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/raj/grpc/server/bank/lb/GrpcServer2.java) runs on port 7575.
The code of the both servers are same expect the port.

Now I want to implement client side load balancing for these servers.

I've `ServiceRegistry` class as follows -

```
import io.grpc.EquivalentAddressGroup;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ServiceRegistry {

    private static final Map<String, List<EquivalentAddressGroup>> MAP = new HashMap<>();

    public static  void register(String service, List<String> instances) {
        MAP.put(service, toEquivAddrGroup(instances));
    }

    public static List<EquivalentAddressGroup> getInstances(String service) {
        return MAP.get(service);
    }
    private static List<EquivalentAddressGroup> toEquivAddrGroup(List<String> instances) {
        return instances.stream().map(i -> i.split(":"))
                .map(a -> new InetSocketAddress(a[0], Integer.parseInt(a[1])))
                .map(EquivalentAddressGroup::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

my `TempNameResolver` class is as follows -

```
import io.grpc.EquivalentAddressGroup;
import io.grpc.NameResolver;
import java.util.List;

public class TempNameResolver extends NameResolver {

    private final String service;

    public TempNameResolver(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public String getServiceAuthority() {
        return "temp";
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Listener2 listener) {
        List<EquivalentAddressGroup> addrGroups = ServiceRegistry.getInstances(this.service);
        ResolutionResult resolutionResult = ResolutionResult.newBuilder().setAddresses(addrGroups).build();
        listener.onResult(resolutionResult);
    }
}
```

`TempNameResolverProvider` class is -

```
import io.grpc.NameResolver;
import io.grpc.NameResolverProvider;
import java.net.URI;

public class TempNameResolverProvider extends NameResolverProvider {

    @Override
    protected boolean isAvailable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int priority() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public NameResolver newNameResolver(URI targetUri, NameResolver.Args args) {
        System.out.println("Looking for service " + targetUri);
        return new TempNameResolver(targetUri.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String getDefaultScheme() {
        return "dns";
    }
}
```

My client code is

```
import client.DepositStreamObserver;
import com.raj.models.*;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.NameResolverRegistry;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ClientSideLoadBalancerTest {

    private BankServiceGrpc.BankServiceBlockingStub bs;
    private BankServiceGrpc.BankServiceStub bss;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() {
        ServiceRegistry.register("bank-service", Arrays.asList("localhost:6565", "localhost:7575"));
        NameResolverRegistry.getDefaultRegistry().register(new TempNameResolverProvider());
        ManagedChannel mc = ManagedChannelBuilder

                //.forAddress("localhost", 8585)
                .forTarget("bank-service")
                .nameResolverFactory(new TempNameResolverProvider())
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
        this.bs = BankServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(mc);
        this.bss = BankServiceGrpc.newStub(mc);
    }

    @Test
    public void balanceTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            BalanceCheckRequest bcr = BalanceCheckRequest.newBuilder().setAccountNumber(i).build();
            Balance b = this.bs.getBalance(bcr);
            System.out.println("balance received " + b.getAmount());
        }
    }
```

The above code is working fine. when I remove or comment the deprecated code `.nameResolverFactory(new TempNameResolverProvider())` so that the global name resolution would work, the application fails with below error -

> WARNING: [Channel<1>: (bank-service)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host bank-service, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: bank-service: Temporary failure in name resolution
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bank-service: Temporary failure in name resolution
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1638)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:997)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1628)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1494)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
> ... 5 more
> }
> error occurred : UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host bank-service
>
> UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host bank-service
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host bank-service
> at app//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
> at app//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
> at app//io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
> at app//com.raj.models.BankServiceGrpc$BankServiceBlockingStub.getBalance(BankServiceGrpc.java:284)
> at app//client.lb.ClientSideLoadBalancerTest.balanceTest(ClientSideLoadBalancerTest.java:39)
> at java.base@18/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base@18/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
> at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
> at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@18/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base@18/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
> at java.base@18/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base@18/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
> at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: bank-service: Temporary failure in name resolution
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bank-service: Temporary failure in name resolution
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1638)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:997)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1628)
> at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1494)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
> at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
> ... 5 more

I don't know why the global service name resolution is not working. What is wrong with my code?

The complete code on the github is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/grpc-gradle-demo)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace schema `dns` in `TempNameResolverProvider#getDefaultScheme` as others like `http`, if you use `dns`, will resolve service name by `DnsNameResolver`.

Comment: I changed the scheme to "http" but still I get  the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and found two issue:

1. The custom `NameResolver` priority need grater than 5, because the default dns name resolver priority is 5, if has same priority, the dns will be used by default. The priority could be 0-10.
2. You need handle scheme prefix when register service in `ServiceRegistry#register`, add scheme prefix `dns:///` to authority `bank-service`. Or remove prefix when `getInstances`, because when create `NameResolver`, will use scheme as prefix. The `bank-service` will be registed  as `dns:///bank-service`

And I suggest use a independent scheme avoid same as others when using register center like consul etc.

If you have more requirement for grpc-java, you can reference the repo https://github.com/helloworlde/grpc-java-sample for more detail.